# iPhone app is region locked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, region

First I need to mention that I'm not a developper, but I can probably work my way around enough in xcode to fix this little issue.

I submitted an application to the app store (that was developped by someone else who's not available right now), but it was rejected because it's "geolocked", meaning the application can only be accessed if you set your international "Region format" setting to Canada.

I need to know what modification I need to make in order for this app to work on all region formats. Is it a string I need to change or is it hidden in a plist file ? I have the feeling the fix is quite easy to apply.

Comment: search for "your country is not supported" in the project and add the surrounding code to your question. 10 lines above and 10 below or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve never heard of an iPhone app using region formats to prohibit launches. I suspect your developer put this code in either out of naïveté or malice; either way, you’ll need to look for a section of code that inspects the region settings.

Comment: I'll look into that (the developper and the section). This is what the error message looks like http://i.imgur.com/Rn6gL.jpg

Comment: Interesting, never saw this message.

Comment: I bet 10$ that this is a UIAlert added by the developer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of something like "geolocking" of iOS application. The only thing you can do, which is quite close to your question, is to set in which countries is this application available. This can be set in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Actually, I **want** the app to be only available in the Canadian app store (which is currently the way it's set in itunes connect), but I want it to be available even if you set your phone to a different country in region format.